# How to find a keyword over mulitiple files using VsVim

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vim, vsvim

When using **VsVim**, the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> is accupied by VsVim itself and if you know `vim` it basically scrolls you forward in your text for approximately one page.

[image]

So I started to wonder if there is any feature in VsVim which can replace the traditional **Quick Find** in `Visual Studio`. If I want to search for a key-phrase using <kbd>/</kbd> then I only get the finds in the current file and missing the good ol **Quick Find** functionality which you could set **Current Project** or the **Entire Solution** to find the matches of what you have searched in the files that you haven't even opened already but may contain the word you're looking for.

Any suggestion? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VsVim gives you control over what it handles and what you let VsVim handle. I suggest you simply tell VsVim not to handle <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and use the Visual Studio behavior. This can be changed in `Tools -> Options -> VsVim -> Keyboard`. If you still need the Vim behavior of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, you can use <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, or you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to scroll down about a half-page.

Answer (score 1):

If VsVim is Vim, `/foo` is good for navigation but not really for searching.

To search for `foo` in the current file and display an actionnable list of results do:

```
:vim foo % | cw
```

To search recursively for `foo` in all `*.py` files under the working directory and display an actionnable list of results do:

```
:vim foo **/*py | cw
```

Vim doesn't know what a project is or what a solution is so I'm afraid you'll have to find your own abstraction for those things.

(edit)

So it looks like VsVim is *not* Vim after all, but maybe [this entry in the FAQ](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/faq#options) will help you.

Comment: hahaha, yeah. `VsVim` is an add-on for `Visual Studio` which lets you use VIM consents on the editor. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Yeah and `:vimgrep` is not currently implemented, and no one has requested it yet, so it doesn't look like it's on the docket at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin for Vim: https://github.com/skwp/greplace.vim

Basically, it allows you to type in a search phases (with/without regex) and ask you for the files to search in.

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin will not work in VsVim until we make a lot more progress on implementing VimScript for it.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will bring up the "Find and Replace" pop up window in which you can choose the scope of your search.